# C# calling a exe in reference

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have added a exe file as a reference in my asp.net project. But it seems like i am unable to trigger it using a process. currently i'm using the follow code to trigger my exe. but it seems that it only worked when i give the fullpath of the exe e.g "c:/file/myEXE.exe"

```
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "myEXE.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = path;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
    int exitCode = process.ExitCode;
```

How should i code it so that the process would be able to tigger my exe from my reference?

Thanks!

Comment: Simply giving the filename assumes you want to start the exe from the current folder. Is this the case?

Comment: but when i add the exe as a reference, the exe is added to the bin folder in the project files

Comment: is the .exe in the bin directory. Have you set the copy to Output directory to always?

Comment: when i add the reference, yes, it turn out to be in the bin directory. what is the purpose of copy to Output directory to always??? sorry I'm quite new to this

Comment: hi dave hogan, i have change the out directory to the project root folders. added reference are not in the root folder. but I'm still unable to trigger myEXE.exe file

Comment: try specifying the absolute path to the exe file, see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

A few points to make here.

First, as other's have said in comments, you do not need to add an executable assembly as a reference to your project just to have it copied to the bin folder on a build. Simply add the executable as a project item, right-click on it and select `Properties` to see the Properties window and change the `Copy to Output Directory` value to `Copy if Newer`. Now whenever you build your project that file will get copied to the bin/output folder.

Secondly, as @trailmax has also mentioned in the comments, you might want to give a full path to the executable to make sure that it can definitely find it.

And finally, as you mention that this is an ASP.NET project, you might want to look at this knowledge base article:

[Unable to Start a Process from ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555134)

I'm not saying that this is the reason for your problem, but it is a possibility since if you are running under IIS you might not have the necessary permissions to start a new process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes peter,

thanks for the advice, now I'm able to make it work.

```
public string checkPlatform(string path)
{
    //new process
    Process process = new Process();
    //required to change the path during hosting.
    string exelocation = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
    process.StartInfo.FileName = exelocation+"\\BitCheck.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = path;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
    int exitCode = process.ExitCode;
    switch (exitCode)
    {
        case 0:
            return "X86";
        case 1:
            return "X64";
        case 2:
            return "ANY";
        case 3:
            return "ERROR";
    }
    return "ERROR";
}
```

Basically, I just need this line here to get the current working directory path

```
string exelocation = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
```

Thanks for the advice and attention

Cheers